# eMail with attachment using java mail api in android

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I am beginning with android and this is my first program.

This is what my code looks like.
I am able to send an email (in background) using this code but unable to attach a file with that as email attachment.
I have given permission in mainfest.xml

Please let me know what I am doing wrong and what need to be implemented.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.activation.CommandMap; 
import javax.activation.DataHandler; 
import javax.activation.DataSource; 
import javax.activation.FileDataSource; 
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap; 
import javax.mail.BodyPart; 
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart; 
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication; 
import javax.mail.Session; 
import javax.mail.Transport; 
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart; 

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;


public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
  private String _user; 
  private String _pass; 

  private String[] _to; 
  private String _from; 

  private String _port; 
  private String _sport; 

  private String _host; 

  private String _subject; 
  private String _body; 

  private boolean _auth; 

  private boolean _debuggable; 

  private Multipart _multipart; 


  public GMailSender() { 
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    _port = "465";
    _sport = "465";

    _user = "";
    _pass = "";
    _from = "";
    _subject = "";
    _body = "";

    _debuggable = false;
    _auth = true;

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

     MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
  } 

  public GMailSender(String user, String pass) { 
    this(); 

    _user = user; 
    _pass = pass; 
  } 

  public boolean send(String to, String from, String subject, String text) {
        return send(new String[] {to}, from, subject, text);
    }
    public boolean send(String[] to, String from, String subject, String text) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", _user);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", _pass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[to.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++) {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
            }
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(text);
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 
    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
  }

  private Properties _setProperties() { 
    Properties props = new Properties(); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 
    if(_debuggable) { 
      props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    } 
    if(_auth) { 
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
    } 
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 
    return props; 
  } 
  // the getters and setters 
  public String getBody() { 
    return _body; 
  } 
  public void setBody(String _body) { 
    this._body = _body; 
  } 
  // more of the getters and setters ….. 
}
```

And how I am calling it in my activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.Log;

public class mailActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new PostTask().execute();

        finish();
     }

    public class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>  {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.d("doInBackground","You are in do in background ... ");

            String filepath = "/storage/sdcard0/Bluetooth/2012.jpg"; 

            Time now = new Time();
            now.setToNow();
            GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("from.xxx@gmail.com","XXX.Password");
            try {
                    sender.addAttachment("/storage/sdcard0/Bluetooth/2012.jpg");
                    sender.send("to.xxx@gmail.com", "from.xxx@gmail.com", "Silent Mail:" + now.format("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"), "This eMail was sent silently in background");

            catch (Exception e) {                   
                Log.e("doInBackground","Mail Exception...");
                Log.e("doInBackground", "exception: " + e.toString());
                }
            Log.d("doInBackground", "You completed do in background ... ");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just check whether you are passing correct `filePath` or not. Try to check whether file exist or not.

Comment: @VikalpPatel : The file path is correct and I am triple sure the file is present in there...

Comment: hiiiiiiii have u slove your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
package com.mail.example;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class SendFileEmail
{
 public void send(String filepath)
 {

  // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
  String to = "abc@gmail.com";

  // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
  final String from = "xyz@gmail.com";
 // final String username = "xyz";
  final String pass = "xyz123";
  // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
  String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

  // Get system properties
  Properties properties = System.getProperties();

  // Setup mail server
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
  properties.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
  properties.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
  properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
  properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
  properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

  //Read more: http://mrbool.com/how-to-work-with-java-mail-api-in-android/27800#ixzz3E2T8ZbpJ


  // Get the default Session object.
  //Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);


  Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(from, pass);
        }
    });


  try{
     // Create a default MimeMessage object.
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

     // Set From: header field of the header.
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

     // Set To: header field of the header.
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                              new InternetAddress(to));

     // Set Subject: header field
     message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

     // Create the message part 
     BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

     // Fill the message
     messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body");

     // Create a multipar message
     Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

     // Set text message part
     multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

     // Part two is attachment
     messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
     DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filepath);
     messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
     messageBodyPart.setFileName(filepath);
     multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);


     MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
     mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
     mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
     mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
     mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
     mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content- handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");

     // Send the complete message parts
     message.setContent(multipart);
     // Send message
     Transport.send(message);
     System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
  }catch (MessagingException mex) {
     mex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
 }
```

call the method like this

```
public class SendMail {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SendFileEmail().send("sample.xlsx");
}

}
```

If the file is in asset folder example test.txt

```
File f = new File(getCacheDir()+"/test.txt");
if (!f.exists()) try {

InputStream is = getAssets().open("test.txt");
int size = is.available();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
is.read(buffer);
is.close();


FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
fos.write(buffer);
fos.close();
 } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }

new SendFileEmail().send(f.getPath());
```

Comment: The file is present in external non-removable storage, it is not an asset file.

Comment: This answer helped me, I took a reference of your code and made necessary changes to my code and it simply worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, clean up your code by [getting rid of the socket factory stuff that's not needed](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

The reason nothing's being attached is that you're adding a body part to the multipart, but you're never using the multipart.  You need to set the multipart as the content of your message, and the multipart needs to include body parts for the main text body and the attachment.  See also the MimeBodyPart.attachFile method.

Comment: I am not able to understand what you trying to say, can you please tell it in terms of code? I have uploaded my code, please let me know what to remove and what to modify... Thanks

Comment: JavaMail comes with tons of sample code to help you.  Download it from [here](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples) and look at the sendfile.java example.