# Java: Sending e-mail with attachment: Impossible to send the attachment

Tags: java, android, email

I'm working on creating an app but I'm having a problem. After I've inserted some data in a file named "message.txt", I'm not able to send this file by e-mail because my smartphone says "impossible to send the attachment". How can I resolve this problem?

This is the code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String address = ...
    byte[] messagetosend = ...
    String filename = "message.txt";
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
    FileOutputStream outputstream;
    try {
        outputstream = openFileOutput(filename,MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        outputstream.write(messagetosend);
        outputstream.flush();
        outputstream.getFD().sync();
        outputstream.close();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{address});
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
    sendIntent.setType("*/*");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Send with..."));
    }
```

Comment: Is file name,path is correct.You have permissions to read the file?

Comment: how can I have the permissons to read the file?

Answer (score 0):

Third party apps have no rights to access that file. Use `FileProvider` to serve it, or copy the file to [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) instead of [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Comment: Trying  http://www.droidviews.com/how-to-setfix-file-permissions-on-android-devices-a-beginners-guide/  will help?Never done that..

Comment: @xyz: That blog post has nothing to do with app development.

Comment: I've tried writing the file out to external storage and Gmail (for example) recognize the attachment, but when I click on the button to Send the e-mail, a notification appears on the notification bar that says "Impossible to send the attachment". Do you kno why?

Comment: @PaoloGuizzardi: Since I cannot see your code for this, I do not really know. If nothing else, call `flush()`, then `getFD().sync()`, and then `close()` on your `FileOutputStream`, not just `close()`, to ensure all bytes are written to disk before you try invoking some other app to work with that file.

Comment: To the code shown above, I've added this calls you told me and modified "getFilesDir" with "getExternalFilesDir". Now Gmail reads the file but says me "Impossible to send the attachment". I don't really know why.

Comment: @PaoloGuizzardi: Hmmmm... if you are still using `Uri.fromFile()`, I would expect Gmail to be reasonably happy with what you describe. Are you sure that you're not having a problem in your `try`/`catch` that is just quietly being dumped somewhere? I never use `e1.printStackTrace();`, but instead use `Log.e()` to ensure the exception makes it out at error severity. Also, in your case, you don't want to go through the `startActivity()` stuff if that disk I/O fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you have saved the file as being private to the app, 
the app can see if fine but the external email client will not be able to see it.
You'll need to write it out to external storage, or make it public. [visit this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) and [visit this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) you will understand about access levels.

OR try to send email with JavaMail [here is solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a), [here is too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032003/email-with-attachment-using-java-mail-api-in-android)

Comment: I've tried writing the file out to external storage and Gmail (for example) recognize the attachment, but when I click on the button to Send the e-mail, a notification appears on the notification bar that says "Impossible to send the attachment". Do you kno why?

Comment: do you realy need to do this type of work using intent? if you want to send the attachment via Gmail only then use java lib for sending email.

Comment: i want to send the attachment via gmail or any other app of mail sending. i know only this method to do this. can you link me the java lib?

Comment: if your problem is solved. accept answer OR let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Sorry but I need to use the Intent. I've updated the code with the last code. Can you see if there is any other problem?

Comment: in you try/catch block print the exception if to know about the file status.