# Mail send text + Image - > Server

Tags: android

I want send image to server with your respective text.

I have challenge with class "**Mail**" , my server have WebMail(RoundCube), but I don't know how send image (bytes/transformText - > Image/etc.)

I use this class **MAIL** : To sender

http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android

```
private Mail m;
m = new Mail("tester@hotmail.com", "passtester");
String[] toArr = {"test@hotmail.com"};
m.setTo(toArr); 
m.setFrom("test@hotmail.com"); 
m.setSubject("Subject");
m.setBody(""+ticket_id \n ""+Here put image[bytes?] );
```

I get correctly text, but I do not found guide to send image.

Thanks.

Comment: store the image locally and send it as an attachment along with the mail. it is easy to done as your using java mail .

Comment: maybe it has a setAttachment or somthing like this

Comment: @warped did you solved your problem ?

Comment: now I trying put image with "attachment", I will try do more test. after I'll comment thanks

Comment: I solved with   "m.addAttachment(MainActivity.photoPath);"  (It is not the way I wanted, but it works.), thanks   @King of Masses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending the image along with text, firstly you can store your image some were locally and get the path and send it as an attachment with mail. i already achieved the same in my case.

There is two ways to achieve it.

1. By using Simple Intent

Look into my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28809905/3983054)

2. By using JavaMail

You can use JavaMail API to handle your email tasks. JavaMail API is available in JavaEE package and its jar is available for download. Sadly it cannot be used directly in an Android application since it uses AWT components which are completely incompatible in Android.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/3983054) from Vinayak B  may help you to solve your problem and if you face any problem follow this link [too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032003/email-with-attachment-using-java-mail-api-in-android)

Comment: I save the solution, if I need it in time +1