# i am trying to send email with attachment , but when i click send the mail is sent but without attachment(without any intent))

Tags: java, android, android-afilechooser

**so what i want to do with my app is:**

i want to send feedback to certain email address with attachment.
but when i try to click send button the mail is sent but there is no file attached with the mail and it throws "open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)" error.

i want to give full path of selected file(for which i am using aFileChooser) to the string "path"
so that it can read the file name and attach it with mail.

at the end i want to attach any image file with mail.

guide me mates.

**here is my Gmail.java file**

```
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;



public class GMail {


    final String emailPort = "587";
    final String smtpAuth = "true";
    final String starttls = "true";
    final String emailHost = "smtp.gmail.com";

    String fromEmail;
    String fromPassword;
    List<String> toEmailList;
    String emailSubject;
    String emailBody;

    Properties emailProperties;
    Session mailSession;
    MimeMessage emailMessage;





    public GMail(String fromEmail, String fromPassword,
                 List<String> toEmailList, String emailSubject, String emailBody) {
        this.fromEmail = fromEmail;
        this.fromPassword = fromPassword;
        this.toEmailList = toEmailList;
        this.emailSubject = emailSubject;
        this.emailBody = emailBody;

        emailProperties = System.getProperties();
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", emailPort);
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", smtpAuth);
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", starttls);
        Log.i("GMail", "Mail server properties set.");
    }

    public MimeMessage createEmailMessage() throws AddressException,
            MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, URISyntaxException {

        mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
        emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

        emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail, fromEmail));
        for (String toEmail : toEmailList) {
            Log.i("GMail","toEmail: "+toEmail);
            emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(toEmail));
        }
        emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
        emailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");// for a html email
        // emailMessage.setText(emailBody);// for a text email

        //String path="storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Ghost335.jpeg";

        String path ;
        path = toString();
        Multipart _multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(path);

        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(path);

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        emailMessage.setContent(_multipart);


        Log.i("GMail", "Email Message created.");
        return emailMessage;
    }

    public void sendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(emailHost, fromEmail, fromPassword);
        Log.i("GMail","allrecipients: "+emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        Log.i("GMail", "Email sent successfully.");
    }

}
```

**and here is FeedbackActivity.java file**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.utils.FileUtils;

public class FeedbackActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = null;
    private Button sendEmail;
    private Button chooseFileButton;
    private String filename;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String pathname;
    public static final int REQUEST_CHOOSER = 1234;
    private static final int FILE_SELECT_CODE = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // Get the Uri of the selected file
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    Log.d(TAG, "File Uri: " + uri.toString());
                    // Get the path
                    String path = FileUtils.getPath(this, uri);
                    Log.d(TAG, "File Path: " + path);
                    // Get the file instance
                    //File file = new File(path);
                    // Initiate the upload

                }
                break;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

        try {
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                    FILE_SELECT_CODE);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feedback);
        final Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("FeedbackActivity", "Send Button Clicked.");

                String fromEmail = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserEmail))
                        .getText().toString();
                String fromPassword = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword))
                        .getText().toString();
                final String toEmails ="devemail@gmail.com";
                List<String> toEmailList = Arrays.asList(toEmails
                        .split("\\s*,\\s*"));
                Log.i("FeedbackActivity", "To List: " + toEmailList);
                String emailSubject = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextSubject))
                        .getText().toString();
                String emailBody = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage))
                        .getText().toString();

                new SendMailTask(FeedbackActivity.this).execute(fromEmail,
                        fromPassword, toEmailList, emailSubject, emailBody );


            }
        });



        chooseFileButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        chooseFileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Create the ACTION_GET_CONTENT Intent

                        showFileChooser();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**SendMailTask.java file**

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.mehul.takeshot.GMail;

public class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask {

    private ProgressDialog statusDialog;
    private Activity FeedbackActivity;

    public SendMailTask(Activity activity) {
        FeedbackActivity = activity;

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        statusDialog = new ProgressDialog(FeedbackActivity);
        statusDialog.setMessage("Getting ready...");
        statusDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        statusDialog.setCancelable(false);
        statusDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... args) {
        try {
            Log.i("SendMailTask", "About to instantiate GMail...");
            publishProgress("Processing input....");
            GMail androidEmail = new GMail(args[0].toString(),
                    args[1].toString(), (List) args[2], args[3].toString(),
                    args[4].toString());
            publishProgress("Preparing mail message....");
            androidEmail.createEmailMessage();
            publishProgress("Sending email....");
            androidEmail.sendEmail();
            publishProgress("Email Sent.");
            Log.i("SendMailTask", "Mail Sent.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            publishProgress(e.getMessage());
            Log.e("SendMailTask", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
        statusDialog.setMessage(values[0].toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        statusDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

**and here is activity_feedback.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FeedbackActivity"
    android:id="@+id/activity_feedback">

    <TextView
        android:text="User Email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextUserEmail" />

    <TextView
        android:text="User Password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Subject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextSubject" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:lines="4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextMessage" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Send"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="choose"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use the following link, which is worked perfectly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032003/email-with-attachment-using-java-mail-api-in-android#answer-27032266

Comment: Where does your `path` variable point to? You some line commented and then you assign the return value of function `toString()` to it. That function is not shared by the way

Comment: i want to take the file path i will get from onActivityResult() method from the FeedbackActivity to that path in the GMail.java class where the creatEmailMessage() will read it and give the file to the setcontent()

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is

```
    String filename="contacts_sid.vcf"; 
    File filelocation = new   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), filename);
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(filelocation); 
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    // set the type to 'email'
    emailIntent .setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
    String to[] = {"asd@gmail.com"};
    emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);

    // the attachment
    emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);

    // the mail subject
    emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent , "Send email..."));
```

Make sure you have these permissions as well

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: mate , i can send the mail without the intent . what i am trying to do is to send mail with attachment (i am attaching file by aFileChooser) without any external app.